# Colleague wants web apps to behave like Windows desktop programs

Tags: asp.net, paradigms

I have been creating new ASP.Net web apps for my workplace intranet (it is a closed system, not accessible to customers) and also re-creating some existing Windows programs as web applications. One colleague always suggests that things work more like a Windows desktop program - things that would take extensive effort with JavaScript for example (of which I have only a small amount of experience) to implement, and which only the requestor is likely to notice. Our primary internal tools are all moving to a browser-based, externally mandated production system now, and so I have been following those standards.

This colleague always asks, "could there be an Hourglass?" for anything that is not instantaneous. Also, "could there be a piece of JavaScript that explains that it is searching?" or whatever the scenario is. I had previously done this for some particularly long-running pages. That is more effort than our in-house system needs. Another issue arose over how to update data. The suggestion was to have a button to switch to Edit mode, then save the data if the user navigates away or closes the page. But the web server doesn't know that you have closed the browser window or navigated away. (Yes, it could be done with JavaScript, but is not necessary.) Another request is for a message to appear on the page to say "Click *Update* to save your changes" as soon as *any* alteration is made to the data on the screen.

My approach when using ASP.Net for pages that simply edit a single row in a table (not insert or delete) is to have the DetailsView or FormView launch in Edit mode, with the standard link buttons labelled *Update* and *Cancel* at the bottom. If the user closes or navigates away, no data change happens - which seems very intuitive to me (and requires no code). The suggested way feels a bit like leaving the car in Drive when you stop and having it roll away when you get out of it.

Are my colleague's suggestions reasonable, or do they reflect a lack of experience with web applications? To me, these suggestions are not just inappropriate to the browser app situation, they are actually harmful. It would add lots of needless and error-prone development for me. How can I approach this? My manager has not heard these one to one discussions and likely has no opinion, but I will bring it up when possible.

Comment: Have you asked your users what they want?

Comment: @PhilipKendall No, because I am leading things in to a new modality, and the users often have difficulty with the very most basic things imaginable in Windows and the browser. If I asked them what they wanted, they would say, "Faster Pencils" ha ha

Comment: The fundamental problem is that things that were easy to achieve 35 years ago, or came with an application by default, have become difficult, long-winded tasks with web development. It's hard to avoid the conclusion that you're taking working Windows apps and substituting them with inferior web apps, because you lack the high skill and extensive experience necessary to reproduce the functionality that comes free in Windows. (1/2)

Comment: The specific problem is likely not hourglasses - it's *some means* by which the computer indicates that it is actually busy working, because that matters to users. Similarly, the view mode/edit mode distinction is likely about avoiding unintended changes by the user being explicit about their intentions, and having been explicit, avoiding the unintended loss of changes (particularly where the overlapping windowed UI of a Windows application, has been replaced by something far less well-integrated). (2/2)

Comment: It seems your colleague is specifying solutions instead of asking you to solve problems;      Of course users who are familiar with one particular system will naturally explain what they want in the context of whatever they're used to, but you need to find out what their needs really are so that you can define the underlying problems that they have in mind instead, by focusing on what their goals are in using the system, rather than taking their attempted solution design as requirements.

Comment: @BenCottrell Colleague is a programmer.

Comment: @Steve The browser does show when it is busy. I am thinking that if all those Windows features are so useful, the browser maker should simply appropriate them and make them happen on web pages. Failing that, I think that people should... adapt to change over time.

Comment: ASP.NET Web Forms is not designed to mimic Windows Forms, nor should it be expected to.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So, cars are not just faster horses? Perhaps you could write a helpful Answer to this question.

Comment: My 3 year old car seems much... better.... than my 25 year old car of the same model. Progress?

Comment: { shrug } You already knew this.

Comment: Is there any expectation that these new web apps will be run on non-Windows devices (tablets, phones, laptops running Linux, etc.)? If so, you don't want to force the Windows look-and-feel and instead should keep as much of the native experience that the user would expect.

Comment: You wrote your colleague is a programmer - but is he/she involved into the development of the replacement apps?

Comment: ... besides that, my usual approach for dealing with such requirements is to make a table listing each individual change request, try to give an honest estimate on how long it would take to implement, add a reasonable safety margin to it (especially when research would be involved), and also put a note about the alternatives in the same row. Don't forget to mention the features for which you think they are more important, and estimate them, too. Then make a priorization, with the people together in one room who have the authority to decide about the priorities ...

Comment: ... maybe your boss, maybe that other colleague (from what you wrote it is not clear if the colleague has any authority in this - if yes, bring them in).  There is a certain chance your colleagues "great ideas" will get a priority so low they will never become realized within, say, the next 12 months, and when people reevaluate at them at that point in time again, they may look a lot less important to them than today.

Comment: if they program, tell him / her to learn C# and write their own **** native apps. Btw does your company have anyone working IT? If it is taking long enough to need a loadscreen on a private server, either something is wrong w/ the app (which it sounds like you know what you are doing) or else something is wrong with the network. Also, shouldn't be your job, or your colleague's job, to update java... unless they are IT.  All in all, they probably feel intimidated by you if they are a programmer not programming for a living. less successful? Id say their is a bit more going on under the surface.

Comment: The specific points raised by your colleague aside, are they communicating things that match with the end user acceptance criteria, i.e. is he actually quite aware of what is needed? Or is he injecting his own personal flavor of scope screep, i.e. features nobody asked for and he just thinks up?

Comment: @NathanToulbert Some data queries go to tables with millions of rows, on columns not indexed. That is a separate issue. Also, the web server seems to "forget" the compiled ASP.Net versions sometimes and recompile or something. Network problems occasionally too, oh my

Comment: @DocBrown Thanks for the suggestion of keeping a running list, perhaps that will help. I was just shortcutting the process by thinking, "this is not very important", but data is more convincing, and I could be wrong about the relative priority.

Comment: DBA then?  XD   Agreed, separate issue indeed.

Comment: @BreaakingGnus, my current car 3 1/2 years old is no better in usability than a previous car made over 20 years ago. In fact it's actually inferior - it doesn't have a front demister (the ones with the embedded wires that will melt ice), whereas the old one did. And the new one is not as maintainable either. Best to just accept the reality that your current work is basically regressive in terms of UI, rather than casting it merely as a change, and either (a) steamroller your colleague anyway, (b) make the case that there are other advantages, or (c) leave those old apps alone.

Comment: @Steve You bought the wrong car. Mine is quieter, smoother, corners better - if that was possible, gets way better gas mileage, and will slow or even stop to avoid hitting something. The stereo is better too. Not sure what more I could want. Web applications are also better than desktop apps, for many reasons. Not having to install and maintain them is a massive advantage, worth a lot of adjusting to UX changes. YMMV

Comment: @BreakingGnus, for any app that is actually designed to have users, there isn't any benefit for which basic usability can sensibly be traded. Your code may be bulletproof, but if using the computer confuses or riles your users or seizes upon their weaknesses, actual data errors will soar through a variety of mechanisms, and that will be your fault. It isn't definite whether your colleague is merely fixed on what he is accustomed to, or is highlighting real shortcomings in usability, but the latter does continue to ring true.

Comment: "*Like enough thou know'st thy estimate.*"

Comment: *"Web applications are also better than desktop apps, for many reasons."* - I question this.  "Easier deployment" is actually the **only** killer feature of Web apps. But YMMV.

Comment: @DocBrown I guess it is a pretty important feature, given how we use computers these days. I can't imagine all the sites and information sources even I (an indifferent user) access, each downloading programs on to my computer. It would be like having different money for everything I buy. The piddly intranet of my organization has a crazy number of various programs. If all the current web resources were recast as desktop programs, it would be impossible. What is Office 365, which we are currently switching to? If it's good enough for Microsoft, it's good enough for me.

Comment: @BreakingGnus: I don't question the importance of web applications today. I question that "Web applications are *generally* better than desktop applications".

Comment: @DocBrown we could ask whether cars are *generally* better than horses, or whether digital music formats are generally better than LPs and FM radio. But we don't. There is no point: that ship has sailed, as it were. Why bother to swim upstream? Funny how technology people seem to cling to the past the most vigorously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirements for a good UX on several points forms a *positive* criticism, and also are present in many if not most web applications.

However they are hard to program oneself, and (especially as there is a plethora of UX features) it would compete with time for business logic development. And JavaScript is not the most qualitative software basis. Even when being content with a mediocre user-interface, that part will cost much development and maintenance effort - doing it yourself. Repairing and improving user-interface can be both costly and unproductively.

So it would be best to use some framework, already offering such UX functionality.
However for ASP.Net I have no experience, as I am on the other - Java - side.
There are also some JavaScript frameworks modeling the application user-interface.

Make a list of UX features and research for a framework: make prototypes.
The invested time will be rewarded by other peoply taking care of any UX problems and having a ready-to-use tool.

Comment: Yes, those were my thoughts in general. I was planning to use Bootstrap, because I had some familiarity with it, perhaps I should push in that direction. I started with a simple approach, but it might be time to advance.

Comment: With web applications where the expectation is a responsive user interface, a good JavaScript framework for the GUI part is a must.

Comment: I'll be looking at the new production system that users will be moving to for ideas for what in the UX to modify.

Answer (score 8):

User expectations should be taken into account when developing software but users are bad sources of UX/UI specifications. You need to have (or be) a UX/UI designer to design a UI that fulfills the various requirements and expectations. For in-house applications, a dedicated UX designer would most likely be overkill (unless your organization happens to have one who's currently not completely booked).

Your colleagues' expectations are actually not unreasonable:

- "wait" indicators are pretty common in web applications. The visual language is a bit different (animated overlay instead of hourglass cursor) but the meaning is the same. Web pages that don't react either quickly or show some wait indicator make users feel insecure about their actions and may trigger unnecessary aborts or retries.
- losing unsaved input data when closing a web page or browser (or using the "back" button) is bad. Many web applications detect this and ask the user if they really want to leave the page. Good UX would be to not only ask this question but explain something like "you entered name and other info, but that input isn't saved yet".

Since developing such UI features does indeed cost time and adds some amout of risk, there must be some sort of cost/value/risk assessment. It would be good if some "neutral" party would do that, not you as the developer or the user, because you're likely to be biased. In business terms, the manager approving the budget for this application may be qualified to decide, but they're also biased (economically).

Comment: _"Good UX would be to not only ask this question but explain something like "you entered name and other info, but that input isn't saved yet"."_ I'd argue that good UX is more about unobstrusive features, i.e. auto-saving as opposed to a blocking message. You could even store it in a cookie (or locally) if the data is too incomplete to make it into the backend - which is what I think StackExchange does with written-but-unposted answers?

Comment: Good comment, and in many cases auto-saving or keeping unsaved edits in local storage my be the right thing to do. In still other cases (especially when dealing with financial stuff or appointments) auto-save isn't what you want, and silently keeping unsaved edits isn't either. So it depends on the specific use case.

Comment: In terms of "budget", just think of me as not completely booked and keeping an infinite, prioritized list of pending work.